# Erase key, value from map by value in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

My map is defined like this:

```
map<string, map<string, string>> _map;
```

But the problem that has come up is that my map's first is mostly the same value, i.e.

```
_map["key1"]["value1"] = "data1";
_map["key1"]["value2"] = "data2";
_map["key1"]["value3"] = "data3";
_map["key1"]["value4"] = "data4";
_map["key2"]["value5"] = "data5";
```

So when I want to delete any particular (key, value), ***I can't use _map.find("key1") for the iterator because it has duplicate entries***.

Is there a way to set the iterator index using the value?

Suppose I want to delete this entry:

```
_map["key1"]["value4"] = "data4";
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. It seems you're asking how to remove an element from a map, which is trivial to find in documentation. Could you clarify just what the problem you're trying to solve is?

Comment: You can't have more than one value per key in a map.

Comment: @A.Franzen: he doesn't have more than one value per key. look closely!

Comment: You use erase or clear.

Comment: Oh I see, you call inner map "keys" "values". That is confusing.

Comment: Take care not to declare a variable by the name `_map` in the global scope, because that name is not allowed in global scope.

Comment: There are no duplicated keys in your map. This, by definition, is impossible. Is like having duplicated indexes in a matrix: it is not possible.

Comment: @ZDF You are right, multimaps support this kind of assignment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nawaz's answer is correct. It does have one weakness, however: If you erase `"value5"`, `_map["key2"]` will still contain an empty `map<string, string>`. This is probably not what you intend.

To fix this, you can use the [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) template and change the type of `_map` to be:

```
map<pair<string, string>, string> _map;
```

Your assignments would then look like:

```
_map[make_pair("key1", "value1")] = "data1";
_map[make_pair("key1", "value2")] = "data2";
_map[make_pair("key1", "value3")] = "data3";
_map[make_pair("key1", "value4")] = "data4";
_map[make_pair("key2", "value5")] = "data5";
```

Then you can remove each entry like:

```
_map.erase(make_pair("key1", "value4"));
```

You can find the [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) type in the `<utility>` header.

Comment: Would his data still be organized in the same order initializing it your way instead of how he has it though? Asking because I genuinely don't know.

Comment: Yes, it would. `std::pair` defines a comparison, which orders first by the first coordinate, then by the second.

Comment: Erase gives me an error. It doesn't recognize the parameter. I'm not able to delete it like that. I tried passing a const pair also, still doesn't work.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Session> >::erase(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Session>)'
     _map.erase(make_pair("contact", session));

Comment: Basically, it's not letting me pass a *pair* to *erase*.

Comment: No, that is not what it's saying. It is not letting you pass a pair of string, Session. You need to pass a pair of strings.

Comment: Any way I can change that to make it pass a pair of string, Session?

Comment: @JørgenFogh My bad, was doing a really silly mistake with the declaration. Can't believe I missed that. It works now :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Just[`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) it:

```
 _map["key1"].erase("value4");
```

Note that it doesn't throw exception if the key doesn't exist — it returns 0 in that case.

BTW, you can improve the initialization of the map as:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> _map 
{
   {"key1", {
               {"value1", "data1"},
               {"value2", "data2"},
               {"value3", "data3"},
               {"value4", "data4"}
             }
    },
    {"key2", {
                {"value5", "data5"}
             }
     }
 };
```